# 2000s cartoon about a group of people interacting with animals, a man turns into a firefly; a logo helps the transformation

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animals

This cartoon is from 2000-2007.

It's about a group of people (4 to 5) one was a girl, they interact with animals... and one episode was about fireflies, a man (one of the group) turned into a firefly (he still had hands and face) and with a flashlight made the rest of the fireflies follow, to secure them. And each episode they used to turn into a different animal.

They had a logo which helped them transform, that looked something like a paw.

Comment: Please also take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in. No matter how minor they may seem; everything might be the key to lead to a successful ID :)

Comment: @Jenayah i fixed some stuff, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Wild Kratts*? It's from 2011 so off by four years but everything matches.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1807859/):

> Chris and Martin Kratt are brothers who explore the wild throughout the world to learn more about animals and share conservation information. They have three friends who travel in the Tortuga HQ with them named Aviva, Koki and Jimmy Z. The brothers have creature power suits that allow them to experience what it's like to be the animals they find. The team helps them by creating power suit creature disks for each animal they study. They also bring them supplies and help them out of tricky situations when their adventures get dicey. The group has to overcome villains as well, like a chef who wants to serve endangered species on his menu, or a clothing designer who wants to trap and use live animals to make her clothing line, or a tech villain who wants to turn animals into robots to do his bidding. All of the villains have no regard for nature or conservation. Wild Kratts is a great cartoon adventure show for kids where they can learn about new animals and why conservation is so important!

Some episodes are available [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxEmDFo1yUbbxjEb9RjitVA); the one you remembered was episode 12, "Fireflies".

And their power suit does look like a paw design:

[image: Armor with paw design]

---

Found with the Google query `tv cartoon animal transformation "firefly"`, [the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLIVP.jpg) looked promising.

Comment: Tank you so much! I was looking for it for so long

Comment: @Straph you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! :D